# Starting cell for copying array

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that I'm using to copy some data from one sheet to another, and I can't for the life of me figure out where I can change the starting cell to B5 on the "OHD Leave Tracker" sheet. It's also starting the copy from the last cell with a value, so if I have something in B26 and run the code again, it will paste the new values from B26.

I think it might be in the line:

```
Target.Range("B" & Lastrow2 & ":D" & Lastrow2).Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(arrData)
```

I have tried the below which doesn't change anything.

```
 Target.Range("B6" & ":D" & Lastrow2).Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(arrData)
```

Edit: I need it to either start from B6 or from the next available cell.

The full code is:

```
Sub CopyNow()

Call ShtArr

    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Dim arrData As Variant: ReDim arrData(2, 0)
    Dim DevList As Object: Set DevList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    'Public SheetArr As String

    'SheetArr =

   Lastrow2 = Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   'Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("B6:D" & Lastrow2).Clear
    With Worksheets("Lists")
        For Each c In .Range("G1", .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            DevList.Add c.Text
        Next c
    End With

    For Each Source In Worksheets(SheetArr)
        Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker")
        With Source
            For Each c In .Range("F1:F100") ', .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If c = "Approved" Then
                    With c.EntireRow
                        If Not DevList.Contains(.Cells(1, 2).Text) Then
                            ReDim Preserve arrData(2, j)
                            arrData(0, j) = .Cells(1, 1)
                            arrData(1, j) = .Cells(1, 2)
                            arrData(2, j) = .Cells(1, 3)
                            'Debug.Assert Trim(.Cells(1, 3)) <> ""
                            j = j + 1
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Next Source
Firstrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("B6")
    Target.Range("B6" & ":D" & Lastrow2).Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(arrData)
    Debug.Print Timer - Start

        Dim Lastrow As Long

    Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("A6:A" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,Lists!G:G,1,FALSE)),""Delete"",""Keep"")"

        Last = Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(i, "A").Value = "Delete" Then
            Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Call SortNow
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("N6:JE6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N6:JE188"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("E6:F6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E6:F188"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Sheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("B5:D" & Lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you working with more than one workbook?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am but not for the purposes of this code. I had a few instances where I ran the code and had the wrong workbook activated, which bugged out, so put the ThisWorkbook in there to alleviate that.

Comment: There is no reason to use `Lastrow2` becuase  `Range("B6" & ":D" & Lastrow2).Resize(j)` resizes the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNow()

    Call ShtArr

    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim arrData As Variant: ReDim arrData(2, 0)
    Dim DevList As Object: Set DevList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker")

        With Worksheets("Lists")
            For Each c In .Range("G1", .Range("G" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp))
                DevList.Add c.Text
            Next c
        End With

        For Each Source In Worksheets(SheetArr)
            With Source
                For Each c In .Range("F1:F100")    ', .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                    If c = "Approved" Then
                        With c.EntireRow
                            If Not DevList.Contains(.Cells(1, 2).Text) Then
                                ReDim Preserve arrData(2, j)
                                arrData(0, j) = .Cells(1, 1)
                                arrData(1, j) = .Cells(1, 2)
                                arrData(2, j) = .Cells(1, 3)
                                'Debug.Assert Trim(.Cells(1, 3)) <> ""
                                j = j + 1
                            End If
                        End With
                    End If
                Next c
            End With
        Next Source

        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Rows(LastRow).Columns("B:D").Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(arrData)
        Debug.Print Timer - Start

        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A5:A" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,Lists!G:G,1,FALSE)),""Delete"",""Keep"")"

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Delete" Then
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

        Call SortNow
        .Range("N5:JE188").AutoFill
        .Range ("E5:F188"), Type:=xlFillDefault

        .Range("B5:D" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
                                                  Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's starting the copy into B5 now, but if there's already data there it's replacing it all. Would I need to put another if statement in there do you think?

Comment: I updated my answer so that the data will be appended to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, That's great!

Comment: Awesome :)  Happy Coding!